# Container not running from image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gunicorn

I have an image `segmentation_site_segmentation_site`. The image is built from the following Dockerfile and Docker-Compose file.

```
junaidali@ubuntu:~/Documents/segmentation/segmentation_site$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY                            TAG            IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
segmentation_site_segmentation_site   latest         e1793ab30737   3 hours ago    3.07GB
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app
```

Docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
    segmentation_site:
        build: .
        command: gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 segmentation_site.wsgi 
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
```

Doing `docker-compose up` runs the image perfectly, as the model loaded shows up.

```
junaidali@ubuntu:~/Documents/segmentation/segmentation_site$ sudo docker-compose up
Starting segmentation_site_segmentation_site_1 ... done
Attaching to segmentation_site_segmentation_site_1
segmentation_site_1  | [2022-05-10 16:36:26 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
segmentation_site_1  | [2022-05-10 16:36:26 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
segmentation_site_1  | [2022-05-10 16:36:26 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
segmentation_site_1  | [2022-05-10 16:36:26 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
segmentation_site_1  | 2022-05-10 16:36:32.195915: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
segmentation_site_1  | 2022-05-10 16:36:32.196645: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
segmentation_site_1  | tensorflow imported.
segmentation_site_1  | 2022-05-10 16:36:46.315257: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
segmentation_site_1  | 2022-05-10 16:36:46.317221: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:269] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
segmentation_site_1  | 2022-05-10 16:36:46.318149: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (73c56bba055c): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
segmentation_site_1  | model loaded.
```

But when I am running this image as container using `docker run e1793ab30737` it shows no output

```
junaidali@ubuntu:~/Documents/segmentation/segmentation_site$ sudo docker run e1793ab30737
junaidali@ubuntu:~/Documents/segmentation/segmentation_site$
```

Can anyone explain what is the right way to run the image docker run command as when this image will be pulled in the deployment location, it can only be run using `docker run` command.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `command: gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 segmentation_site.wsgi` from your `docker-compose.yaml` and put it into your `Dockerfile` like this:

```
CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 segmentation_site.wsgi
```

Otherwise the image doesn't start any process

[Here is the official Dockerfile documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) for more information.